# Type definitions and the size of various types on multi-platform distributions

Tags: pkcs11interop

I'm slightly confused by the PKCS11Interop library's use of types across different OS platforms. My understanding is that the size of a long on Windows x64 is 4 bytes but on Linux/iOS 64bit the length is 8 bytes. This is indeed reflected in the Platform.cs implementation of the public static NativeULongSize. However looking at the LowLevelAPIXX source, where for example LowLevelAPI80 corresponds to Linux (x64), and LowLevelAPI81 corresponds to Windows (x64), the defintion of NativeULong used in the structure defintions is  UInt64 - and so will be 8 bytes.  Is this a mistake - at the very least it seems to be inconsistent?

Comment: Looking again at the source, it is my mistake. I had (incorrectly) assumed that the LowLevelAPI81 corresponded to Windows x64 which actually doesn't seem to be the case. The selection of OS is the platform module for windows is based on the existence of the environment variable "windir". The IntPtr size is handled by the .NET runtime. Apologies for the rather stupid suggestion that it might be a mistake - this is an incredible library.